# Simulating a non-simple exponential distribution

Tags: r, simulation, exponential-distribution

I want to simulate a vector `x` in R with 1000 entries. The j'th entry comes from a exponential distribution with density

$$
f_{j}(x)=j \beta e^{-j \beta x}, x>0
$$

Let us just say that $\beta=2$.

So the first entry in x comes from an exponential distribution with density  $$f_{1}(x)=1 \beta e^{-1 \beta x}, x>0$$

The second entry in x comes from an exponential distribution with density $$f_{2}(x)=2 \beta e^{-2 \beta x}, x>0$$

etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R will happily vectorize the `rate` parameter:

```
beta <- 2
rexp(1000,rate=(1:1000)*beta)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to R, so this is a big deal to me.

Answer (score 6):

General method (shown in R) that does not rely on how R's `rexp` works.

```
set.seed(2021)
n = 1:1000
x = -(1:1000)*log(runif(1000))

plot(n,x)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. What theorem is this based on?

Comment: The CDF of $\mathsf{Exp}(\mathrm{rate}=\beta)$ is $F_X(x) = 1 - e^{-x/\beta},$ for $x > 0.$ Then find the inverse CDF (quantile function). if it exists in closed form. A general method of generating values of $X$ is $F_X^{-1}(U),$ where $U\sim\mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates). In this particular application, note that $1-U \sim\mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ also.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. Nice to know.